# netty channelDuplexHandler write is not called

Tags: netty

ChannelDuplexHandler write method should be called when it is the last handler, but in practice it is not.

From [ChannelPipeline](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html),

```
 ChannelPipeline p = ...;
 p.addLast("1", new InboundHandlerA());
 p.addLast("5", new InboundOutboundHandlerX());
```

the evaluation order of an inbound and a outbound event could be 1,5 and 5 respectively.

So I thought `write` in the following class should be called when `ctx.write()` in `channelRead` is called:

```
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
@Component
public class InboundOutboundHandlerX extends ChannelDuplexHandler {


    @Override
    public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ctx.write(msg); // I have also tried writeAndFlush(msg)
    }

    @Override
    public void write(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg, ChannelPromise promise) throws Exception {
        ctx.write(msg, promise);  
    }

}
```

Is there a special trick to get the last duplex handler write method called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Norman's [slides](http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-facebook-eng-netty/slides.html), this is because `ctx.write()` or `writeAndFlush()` will start from the next handler, not the current, while `ctx.channel().write()` will start from the top (or the tail if that fits a better sense of direction) of `pipeline`.